# Getting Python to recognize newline characters in csv file

Tags: python, csv, newline

Beginner working on first project here.

I have a simple command line flashcard program. The questions and answers are stored in a csv file separated by a ^.
I would like the program to be able to recognize newline (\n) characters in the csv file and be able to divide up the question onto separate lines. How do I do this?

---

An example of a csv file would be:

```
question1^answer1
long\nquestion\nnumber2^answer2
```

---

For example, maybe I had a question about linux. Right the program prints the question like this:

Based on the following diagram, what access would the user bob have on the file abc.txt?        drwxr-xr-x. 17 root root 4096 23:38 /           drwxr-xr--. 10 root root 128  03:38 /data       -rwxr-xr--.  1 bob  bob  100  21:08 /data/abc.txt

---

When I want the program to show me the question like this`:

```
Based on the following diagram, what access would the user bob have on the file abc.txt?
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root root 4096 23:38 /
drwxr-xr--. 10 root root 128  03:38 /data
-rwxr-xr--.  1 bob  bob  100  21:08 /data/abc.txt
```

---

So in the csv file, the question would look like this:

```
Based on the following diagram, what access would the user bob have on the file abc.txt?\ndrwxr-xr-x. 17 root root 4096 23:38 /\ndrwxr-xr--. 10 root root 128  03:38 /data\n-rwxr-xr--.  1 bob  bob  100  21:08 /data/abc.txt^None
```

---

I've looked up online and saw that somebody to add: newline='\n'

---

I've tried lots of different variations of the following with single quotes, double quotes, spaces. I don't know how to get it to work.

with open(studySet, newline="\n") as f:

with open(studySet, newline="\n") as f:

---

I also tried putting it here, but didn't work:

fileContents = csv.reader(f, delimiter='^', newLine='\n')

---

This is a snippet of the code opening the csv file:

```
    with open(studySet) as f:     
        fileContents = csv.reader(f, delimiter='^')
        flashcards = [{"question":rows[0], "answer":rows[1]} for rows in fileContents]
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It is not clear which block contains which part of the code.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `pandas`? and can you post a small sample of the file (for testing purposes)?

Comment: fixed the indentation

Comment: I'm not sure what pandas is. never heard of it before now. And which file? the csv file or the program file?

Comment: [pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) is a very popular package in Python that among other things, can be very handy for reading files in.

Comment: a sample of the csv file, just enough to test that the answer behaves properly. Also with fake data as long as the patterns you mention (e.g. `^`,  and new lines).

Comment: I edited the post with examples and tried to make the question more clear

Answer (score 1):

If you can use / install [pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#where-to-get-it), this is a solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("studySet.csv", sep="^", header=None, names=["question", "answer"]).replace(r'\\n','\n', regex=True)
txt = "\n".join([df.iloc[i]["question"]+"\n" + df.iloc[i]["answer"]  for i in df.index])
print(txt)
```

Comment: How did it go? If it worked, you might want to consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If not, I am happy to assist further (: